# Is the purported "Buddhist Cosmology" found in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda

The Buddhist Pali suttas (the purported words of the Buddha Gotama) contain a "cosmology", which, in the Pali language, includes:

> 1. Gods of the Four Great Kings: Cātumahārājikā Devā
> 2. Gods of the Thirty Three: Tāvatiṃsā Devā
> 3. Gods of Yama: Yāmā Devā
> 4. Joyful Gods: Tusitā Devā
> 5. Gods Who Love to Create: Nimmānaratī Devā
> 6. Gods Who Control the Creations of Others: Paranimmitavasavattī Devā
> 7. Lord of Creation: Pajāpati
> 8. Brahmā
> 9. Gods of Streaming Radiance: Abhassarato Deva
> 10. Gods Replete with Glory: Subhakiṇhato Deva
> 11. Gods of Abundant Fruit: Vehapphalato Deva
> 12. The Overlord: Abhibhū

Are all of the above twelve gods found in the (pre-Buddha) Vedas or, if not, in later Upanishads?

Comment: Rig Veda contains epithets of various forms of the Almighty God.  Deifying of those epithets can be found in later day texts.@Dhammadhatu

Comment: 33 gods, Prajapati, Brahma, Yama are mentioned in RigVeda... regarding other.. 'Devata' comes from 'Div' dhatu which means 'To shine'.. and thus it is used in Vedas to describe psychologically shining things like joyous nature  loving nature etc.. as well as physically shining things like sun, stars, photons, etc...

Comment: There are many questions asked if Buddhist concept present in Hinduism. Those were not closed as off-topic. This wouldn't be off-topic too.